# jqgrid auto-scroll up/down when keyboard popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, mobile, jqgrid

I have a site where everything is fine on desktop (FF, Chrome, IE), but when the site is opened on ipad, if a cell is edited and the keyboard popup, the page will scroll down or up automatically after the edit is completed (click outside of the edit box or click "Go").

the url is http://bambootextiles.com.au/cgi-bin/order.mobile.pl

How to avoid this annoying behaviour?

Thanks